# Can detect the distance (with x, y and z coordinates) from a fixed point in space on Android?

Tags: android, distance

I would like to find the position of an Android device with respect to a fixed point in space.
I need a precision close to one or two meters.
My goal is to determine the position of the android device user inside a building (a museum), to detect the floor and the room she is in, and - if possible - even a more precise position in the room (to know which painting she is close to).
I did already excluded to use GPS, since it is not so precise (expecially with respect to elevation), it only reliably works outdoors, it quickly consumes battery power, and it doesn't return the location quickly.
I did already excluded to use Network Location Provider too, since it is even less accurate.

Comment: I don't think that there are many more options you have in terms of location finding, unless you visually code the whole place and have the camera on.  If this is for displaying information based on what the user is looking at, you might want to take a look at 2d barcodes.

Comment: @bdares that's my opinion as well. 2d barcodes or Google Goggles to recognize the paining or whatever. This is ofc only suitable for museums where you have an exponent with a label.

Comment: "..to detect the floor and the room **she** is in.." you're doing this for work and not spying your wife, right?  ;)

Comment: Oh, forgot to add. While being rather clueless on location/GPS related issues I was wondering whether a GPS signal repeater might help in your case?

Comment: Hey Marcos .have you got the solution for this question..it would be great if you share it?

Comment: @harism: no, I suppose commercial GPS accuracy is not sufficient for this class of problems.

Comment: @nibha: I did conclude the best solution - with today technology - is to detect all nearby wi-fi beacons BSSIDs signal strengths, and to apply a function to minimize the difference with the prerecorded values of the same beacons signal strengths for each point of interest. Of course this poses quite many problems (need to deploy many wifi beacons in the building - which causes interference problems, not complete reliability of the rilevations, and others), so I don't believe this is a solution general and satisfactory enough... :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Android you have three possibilities to detect the location of a Android phone:

1) GPS

2) Network

3) Triangulation

But none of these three possibilities is suited for you're problem. The GPS is the most accurate one, but as you already noticed it is not working in buildings, and it won't be able to differentiate between different floors. The problem is that the accuracy of GPS is at best 3 or 4 meters. The other two possibilities are far less accurate. That's why there isn't a real solution for your problem.

One thing that might be a possibility is the motion sensor. If you know where the user starts, you maybe can use the motion sensor to calculate how many meters the user moves. But I don't think that this is accurate enough.

Comment: Motion sensor most probably is not accurate enough. And, since it returns an acceleration value, you should then twice integrate that value (operation which lets quickly grow errors...) to obtain a position, and would also need three good gyros to obtain the direction of the acceleration. Forget about using the values returned by a flaky compass (if any), also because a compass does not gives any info about Z axis... You are right, I too suppose there is currently no real solution to my problem... :-(